# Remove junk characters from a utf-8 file in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, unicode, strip, null-character

I'm getting the junk chars (`<9f>`, `<9d>`, `<9d>` etc), CNTRL chars (`^Z`,`^M` etc) and `NULL` chars(`^@`) in a file. However I was able to remove `CNTRL` and `NULL` chars from the file but couldn't eliminate the junk characters. Could anyone suggest a way to remove these junk chars?

[image: Screen shot for Junk Data]

Control characters are being removed using the following command:

```
sed 's/\x1a//g;s/\xef\xbf\xbd//g'
```

Null characters are removed using the below command

```
tr -d '\000'
```

Also, Please a suggest a single command to remove all the above mentioned 3 types of garbal characters.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Dos2Unix is also not working. the error states 'problems converting file'

Comment: in what encoding is the file? Can you paste the file on pastebin.com?

Comment: the file encoding is utf-8. Sorry, I couldn't place the file.

Answer (score 2):

## Strip "unusual" unicode characters

In the comments you mention that you want to block out control characters while keeping the Greek characters, so the solution below with tr does not suit. One solution is `sed` which offers unicode support and their `[[:alpha:]]` class matches also alphabetical characters outside ascii. You first need to set [`LC_CTYPE`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Categories.html#index-LC_005fCTYPE) to specify which characters all fall into the `[[:alpha:]]` range. For German with Umlauts, that's e.g.

```
LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8
```

Then you can use `sed` to strip out everything which is not a letter or punctuation:

```
sed 's/[^[:alpha:];\ -@]//g' < junk.txt
```

What `\ -@` does: It matches all characters in the ascii range between space and `@` (see [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Sed has a [`[[:punct:]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html#index-punctuation-characters) class, but unfortunately this also matches a lot of junk, so `\ -@` is needed.

You may need to play around a little with `LC_CTYPE`, setting it to `utf-8` only I could match greek characters, but not japanese.

## If you only care about ascii

If you only care about regular ascii characters you can use `tr`: First you convert the file to a "one byte per character" encoding, since `tr` does not understand multibyte characters, e.g. using `iconv`.

Then, I'd advise you use a whitelist approach (as opposed to the blacklist approach you have in your question) as it's a lot easier to state what you want to keep, than what you want to filter out.

This command should do it:

```
iconv -c -f utf-8 -t latin1 < junk.txt | tr -cd '\11\12\40-\176'
```

this line..

- converts to latin1 (single byte per char) and ignores all characters above codepoint 127 (which are the special characters, but be aware, that strips away also things like umlaut or special characters in your language which you might want to keep!)
- strips all characters away which are outside this whitelist: `\11\12\40-\176`. The numbers there are octal. Have a look at e.g. [this ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/). `\11` is `tab`, `\12` is carriage return. `\40-\176` is all characters which are commonly considered as "normal"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have used this tr -cd '\11\12\40-\176' command already. All the junk characters have been removed. However, I'm losing some greek characters as well. I need those greek chars

Comment: And also if i convert the file from utf-8 to us-latin using iconv i'm losing all the Unicode chars sucha as Japan data, Greek data

Comment: @user2975559 I expanded my answer to also match unicode characters beyond the ascii set, can you check if that solves your problem?